# How to use controller as syntax in the following scenario

Tags: angularjs

### controller as syntax problem

I am a newbie to angular, so please forgive me if i'm wrong. I have a problem where a service is used for certain operation. In this case, adding books to cart.

I have followed the recommended way using controller as syntax instead of $scope. But in kart-list.html, i'm not able to access kart details, since this operation is done by BookListCtrl.

**app.js**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/books", {
      templateUrl: "partials/book-list.html",
      controller: "BookListCtrl",
      controllerAs: 'booklist'
    })
    .when("/kart", {
      templateUrl: "partials/kart-list.html",
      controller: "KartListCtrl",
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: "/books"
    });
});

app.factory("kartService", function() {
  var kart = [];

  return {
    getKart: function() {
      return kart;
    },
    addToKart: function(book) {
      kart.push(book);
    },
    buy: function(book) {
      alert("Thanks for buying: ", book.name);
    }
  };
});

app.factory("bookService", function() {
  var books = ['some data'];

  return {
    getBooks: function() {
      return books;
    },
    addToKart: function(book) {

    }
  }
});

app.controller("KartListCtrl", function(kartService) {
  var self = this;
  self.kart = kartService.getKart();

  self.buy = function(book) {
    kartService.buy(book);
  };
});

app.controller("HeaderCtrl", function() {
  var self = this;
  self.appDetails = {};
  self.appDetails.title = "BooKart";
  self.appDetails.tagline = "We have collection of 1 Million books";
});

app.controller("BookListCtrl", function(bookService, kartService) {
  var self = this;
  self.books = bookService.getBooks();

  self.addToKart = function(book) {
    kartService.addToKart(book);
  };
});
```

**book-list.html**

```html
<div id="bookListWrapper">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="book" ng-repeat="book in booklist.books" style="background: white url('imgs/{{book.imgUrl}}') no-repeat">
      <div class="book-details clearfix">
        <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{book.price}}</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
          <li>Rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
          <li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
          <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
          <li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{book.details}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**kart-view.html**

```html
<div id="bookListWrapper">
  <p>Please click on buy button to buy the book.</p>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="book" ng-repeat="book in kart" style="background: white url('imgs/{{book.imgUrl}}') no-repeat">
      <div class="book-details clearfix">
        <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{book.price}}</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
          <li>Rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
          <li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
          <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
          <li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{book.details}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="buy(book)">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Problem is how use controller as syntax for kart-list.html near ng-repeat to access kart details?

Comment: What output do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: If i add a new book using Add to kart button, the book is not added to kart if i route to kart-list.html

Comment: First obvious mistake: you need `booklist.addToKart(book)`, not just `addToKart(book)`. Otherwise, you're calling addToKart on the $scope, not on the controller.

Comment: uh oh! Thanks for pointing it! Solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Your'e using the `controller as` feature but you haven't covered all view references.

1. **book-list.html**

   ```
   <button ... ng-click="addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
   ```

   Change to

   ```
   <button ... ng-click="booklist.addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
   ```
2. **kart-view.html**

   ```
   <li ... ng-repeat="book in kart" ...
    ...
   <button ... ng-click="buy(book)">Buy</button>
   ```

   Change to

   ```
   <li ... ng-repeat="book in KartListCtrl.kart" ...
    ...
   <button ... ng-click="KartListCtrl.buy(book)">Buy</button>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prefix booklist while calling addToKart() method in book-list.html.

Use below file which will resolve your issue:

### book-list.html

```
<div id="bookListWrapper">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search here..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="book" ng-repeat="book in booklist.books" style="background: white url('imgs/{{book.imgUrl}}') no-repeat">
      <div class="book-details clearfix">
        <h3>{{book.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{book.price}}</p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
          <li>Rating: {{book.rating}}</li>
          <li>Binding: {{book.binding}}</li>
          <li>Publisher: {{book.publisher}}</li>
          <li>Released: {{book.releaseDate}}</li>
        </ul>
        <p>{{book.details}}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-info pull-right" ng-click="booklist.addToKart(book)">Add to Kart</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```